# detect client side software version

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have web application, through I need it to read an application version on the client side.

is this possible? Can I do this in javascript, or even asp.net?

I want to determine the version of software installed on the client side.

For example:

The version of software that is installed, for instance if a user installs a program with name test.exe , I want to detect it and get its version. It's not browser plugin.

Comment: Do you mean the version of both browser and operating system ?

Comment: No , the version of software be installed ,for example if user instal program with name test.exe , I want to detect it and get its version , it's not browser plugin

Comment: I think he meant his web application's version. Am i correct? Any more information on your application, your code etc?

Comment: No I have web application , want to monitor another application on client machine and get its version

Comment: I tried to word this in somewhat proper English. Good luck and may the flying spaghetti have mercy on us all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use activeX to create object of any exposed type using JS. If it fails software is not installed, else u can retrieve version stored in activeX object. Thats how most messenger do.

```
<OBJECT id="MSXML4"
classid="clsid:88d969c0-f192-11d4-a65f-0040963251e5"
codebase="http://www..../msxml4.cab#version=4,10,9404,0"
type="application/x-oleobject"
STYLE="display: none"
standby="ww">
Alternative Text
</OBJECT>

<script>
//if msxml4 is not installed
if( !document.MSXML4 ){
alert("MSXML4 is not installed");
</script>
}
```

Comment: That would be windows+IE only however

Comment: Yes there are limitations. ActiveX supported browser and must be enabled too.

Comment: for ie , ok . how to write the code of MSXML4 , I mean how to do something like that

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreateActiveXDotNet.aspx See how to create activeX. But this way u can only check if ur app is installed or not. I guess you want any app installed on machine should be notified. You can write ur activeX to fetch details of installed application using registry, but that would require neccessary permission, that user has to allow.